# ruby, simple_form Rails, collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have in "View" input with collection (simple_form), but that collection should be in model.

I must to declare a variable which contains ["Brother", "Daughter", "Father", "Friend", "Husband", "Mother", "Sister", "Son", "Wife"] in model and use in in view here:

```
= f.input :relationship
```

That's my View:

```
= simple_form_for @emergency_information, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :relationship, collection: ["Brother", "Daughter", "Father", "Friend", "Husband", "Mother", "Sister", "Son", "Wife"]
```

That's my Model

```
class EmergencyInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :name, presence: true

end
```

Help me, please!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Or if there even is one.

Comment: Does your `emergency_information` table contain an attribute called `relationship`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly Your struggle is to figure out where to attach this array. Usually in these cases I add it as a constant to my model and use it both for listing values and to validate if value submitted is from array.

```
class EmergencyInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  RELATIONSHIPS_TYPES = ["Brother", "Daughter", "Father", "Friend", "Husband", "Mother", "Sister", "Son", "Wife"]
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :name, presence: true
  validates :relationship, inclusion: RELATIONSHIPS_TYPES
end

# in view
= f.input :relationship, collection: EmergencyInformation::RELATIONSHIPS_TYPES
```

Alternatively You can extract this array to separate service object, but in this case it feels like over enginnering.